# Is there any way to represent a glVertex3f by a variable?

Tags: opengl, graphics, types

Is there any way to represent a `glVertex3f`  by a variable?
For example

```
one = glVertex3f(xL, yB, zF);
```

If so, what would be the type of one?
Also, can you build a polygon with the created variable?
Example:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
       one;
       glVertex3f(xR-45, yB, zF);
       glVertex3f(xR-45, yB, zB+55);
       glVertex3f(xL, yB, zB+55);

glEnd();
```

Comment: What you ask for best matches the conecpt of a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) in some programming languages. But you dod not even specify which language you talk about. Howerver, I think that you don't even want closures. You just want to be able to reference vertex data. You should have a look at OpenGL's vertex arrays (and VBOs).

Comment: `struct { double x, y, z; } vertex3` in C. Or even better as derhass said, use Vertex Buffer Objects instead of immediate mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C, it was already answered by Colonel Thirty Two in the comment to OP.
If needed for C++, this is a good way, making use of coercion. 
**Point3D Class**:

```
class Pt3d
{
public:
    // omitting constructors/setters/getters etc
    //
    //
    // ____________________________
    // automatic coercion: 
    // wherever a float* is needed for coordinates, this will kick-in
    operator float* ()const  {  return (float *)m_co; }
private:
        float m_co[3];
};
```

**Usage**:

```
Pt3D p1(/*set coords here*/); 
Pt3D p2(/*set coords here*/);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3fv(p1); 
    glVertex3fv(p2); 
    // so on
glEnd();
```

Comment: Good answer, except for the gratuitous const_cast (written as a C-style cast).  One can also simply use `float[3]`, and that already casts to `float*`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, agreed. But there could be some funcs that take `float*` instead of `const float*` in old Opengl, like GLU tessellation.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you could encapsulate a vertex with a class like this:

```
class Vertex3f {
public:
    Vertex3f(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
        : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z) {
    }

    void apply() const {
        glVertex3f(m_x, m_y, m_z);
    }

private:
    GLfloat m_x, m_y, m_z;
};
```

Following the example in the question, you would instantiate an object of this type:

```
Vertex3f one(xL, yB, zF);
```

And then apply it like this:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
one.apply();
...
```

You could overload the function call operator instead of having the `apply()` method. I think using an explicit method makes the code easier to understand in this case, but it's a matter of personal preference.